# TikZ-Feynman : how to do a feynman diagram of a beta decay?

Tags: tikz-feynman

I would like to create a Feynman diagram of a beta decay using the package `[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}`, but I don't know how. Can someone give me an example? Thanks :)

I would like to draw a diagram like this, I've already found examples that uses other packages that I don't know how to use. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=15mm, y=15mm]
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (i1) {\(u\)};
    \vertex[right=.15 of i1] (i2) {\(d\)};
    \vertex[right=.15 of i2] (i3) {\(d\)};
    \vertex[below=.3 of i2] (n) {\(n\)};

    \vertex[above=2 of i1] (f1) {\(u\)};
    \vertex[right=.15 of f1] (f2) {\(d\)};
    \vertex[right=.15 of f2] (f3) {\(u\)};
    \vertex[above=.3 of f2] (p) {\(p\)};

    \vertex[above=1 of i3] (a);
    \vertex[right=.15 of a] (b);
    \vertex[right=.15 of b] (c);

    \vertex at ($(c) + (1,.25)$) (d);
    \vertex at ($(d) + (.2, 1)$) (f4) {\(\bar{\nu}_e\)};
    \vertex at ($(d) + (.9,.5)$) (f5) {\(e^-\)};
\diagram*{
    (i1) -- [fermion] (a) -- [fermion] (f1),
    (i2) -- [fermion] (b) -- [fermion] (f2),
    (i3) -- [fermion, thick] (c) -- [fermion, thick] (f3),
    (c) -- [boson, edge label'=\(W^-\), thick] (d) -- [fermion, thick] (f5),
    (d) -- [anti fermion, thick] (f4),
};

\draw[-stealth] (-.4,-.4) -- (-.4,2.2);
\node at (-.4,2.3) {\(t\)};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks you :). I dont know how to create this more complex diagrams

Comment: @GabrielVian there are lots of examples in the documentation of the package, you should take a look!